# Style to specify the file name before contents

Tags: discussion

When asking questions, on C language for example, it's often needed to include multiple files, such as .h and .c.

Is there a preferred/standard style to specify the file name before the contents code block?

Comment: Just add a small title:  _"fileName.ext: `<code block>`"_

Comment: Although it would be really great to allow for some kind of title for code blocks.